# Use Gulp to download PHP Packages/Libraries

Tags: php, wordpress, npm, gulp

Im using wordpress quite frequently, and i dont want to have composer to download my packages and then have gulp to create my assets.

It's posible to download the php libraries directly within gulp ?

For example i want to add the libraries in a file libraries.json and execute a gulp-task which will download the php libraries in a desired folder.

Ty.

Comment: What has your research shown till now?

Comment: Trough my research the best solution i fount is gulp-composer. The answer i got was the same like my research.I thought someone had this problem, and a different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to separate your PHP and JS libraries. But if you want to group it you can do it with **gulp-composer**.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-composer

Enjoy

Comment: Ty. I will try it. Much appreciated.